# Если Одигитрия = икона, то возможно ли: Икона Богоматери Одигитрия?

Tags: выбор-слов, прописная-строчная, кавычки

> Смоленская икона Божией Матери, именуемая "Одигитрия", что значит
> "Путеводительница", по преданию, была написана святым евангелистом
> Лукой во время земной жизни Пресвятой Богородицы.
>
> Чудотворная икона Божией Матери «Одигитрия» Смоленская.
>
> Одиги́трия (греч. Οδηγήτρια — Указующая Путь; Путеводи́тельница) —
> один из наиболее распространённых типов изображения Богоматери с
> младенцем Иисусом; иконописный образ, по преданию, написанный
> евангелистом Лукой.
>
> Смоле́нская ико́на Бо́жией Ма́тери (Одиги́трия Смоле́нская) —
> почитаемая в православии икона Богородицы (Одигитрия). Празднование
> иконы совершается 28 июля (10 августа).

Что там с кавычками?

У меня - подпись под репродукцией иконы:

> Икона Богоматери Одигитрия – “Спасения Римского народа”. VII в.

И что за странный падеж у "спасения"? Тогда требуется понять роль тире...

И как быть с Римским народом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смоленская икона Богоматери и Римская - две разные иконы одного типа (первый тип - "Умиление", младенчество Иисуса, второй - "Одигитрия", возрастание, третий - "Оранта", появление на свет и конец жизни).

Композиция иконографии «Одигитрия» такова: Богоматерь и Младенец Христос изображаются почти фронтально, их обращенные к молящемуся лики не соприкасаются. Глава Богородицы может быть немного наклонена к Сыну, рука поднята в молитвенном жесте на уровне груди. Богомладенец восседает на руках Матери; правой рукой Он благословляет, левой — держит свиток, реже — книгу. Богоматерь чаще всего представлена в поясном изображении, но существуют и ростовые и оплечные варианты, например Казанская икона. Младенец может располагаться как справа, так и слева от Богородицы, чаще Он изображается сидящим на левой руке Пресвятой Девы.

Богоматерь Римская (в энциклопедиях есть написание Salus Populi Romani и Salus populi romani) - чудотворная икона, по преданию, написана апостолом Лукой и привезена в Рим с Востока св. царицей Еленой. Дева Мария представлена согласно иконографии «Одигитрия», с Младенцем на скрещенных руках, в левой руке — маппула, небольшой льняной плат, использовавшийся древнеримской знатью.

http://www.icon-art.info/masterpiece.php?lng=ru&mst_id=2432

```
 Икона Богоматери Одигитрия – “Спасения Римского народа”. VII в.
```

Если учитывать правила русского языка, то тип иконы в кавычках -"Одигитрия", римского - со строчной буквы, "Спасение" в именительном падеже. Это же несогласованное приложение.

Она отличается от Смоленской, как видите.

Comment: Конечно, сейчас в искусствоведении — это тип. Тип можно и закавычить. Но в православной традиции ничего не изменилось: "Ты верным людям – Всеблагая Одигитрия, Ты – Смоленская Похвала и всея земли Российския – утверждение! Радуйся, Одигитрие, христианом спасение!"

Answer (score 1):

Кроме Смоленской известны Тихвинская, Иверская... «Одигитрия» — тип иконы (по оригиналу св. Луки) с Богоматерью и Богомладенцем на её левой руке. Богоматерь на ней выступает «путеводительницей», указывая на единственный путь спасения — путь к Богу.

Упор на Римский народ делать можно, если ретроспективный контекст диктует, а также, если это — сохранившееся с VII века автором данное название (что невозможно, скорее всего). Если такой довесок, как второе название, появляется, икона превращается в картину, т. е. светское произведение. Так что, либо икона, либо библейский сюжет.

Правка.

Смоленская (с XI в.) икона Божией Матери святого евангелиста Луки, написанная им как Одигитрия (Путеводительница) во время земной жизни Пресвятой Богородицы.

Чудотворная икона Смоленской Божией Матери «Одигитрия».

Одиги́трия (греч. Οδηγήτρια — Указующая Путь; Путеводи́тельница) — один из наиболее распространённых типов изображения Богоматери с младенцем Иисусом; иконописный образ, созданный, по преданию, евангелистом Лукой.

Смоле́нская ико́на Бо́жией Ма́тери (Одиги́трия Смоле́нская) — почитаемый в православии образ Богородицы. Празднование иконы совершается 10 августа (28 июля ст.ст.).

Comment: См. ответ шорк-шорк (ник такой): http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2789054-esli-odigitrija--ikona-to-vozmozhno-li-ikona-bogomateri-odigitrija.html#answer8192149 Мне очень важно разобраться!

Comment: Греческий император Константин IХ Мономах (1042-1054), выдавая в 1046 году свою дочь Анну за князя Всеволода Ярославича, сына Ярослава Мудрого, благословил ее в путь этой иконой. После смерти князя Всеволода икона перешла к его сыну Владимиру Мономаху, который перенес ее в начале ХII века в Смоленскую соборную церковь в честь Успения Пресвятой Богородицы. С того времени икона получила название Одигитрия Смоленская.

Comment: Но меня интересует "Спасение римского народа". Одигитрия или нет?

Comment: Ваши интересы покинули зону интересов сайта. Это ведь не наша языковая проблема. Солнце высоко, Константинополь далеко.

Comment: Почему же?! У меня метки: ***прописная-строчная, употребление-слов, кавычки***, и главное - народ с удовольствием откликнулся и всё разложил по полочкам... А если это не *русский язык*, то какой?

Comment: Вас интересует "Спасение римского народа". Одигитрия или нет? Это — не про русский язык. А то, что народ заводной, это верно.

Comment: ***Падеж*** у "Спасения...", ***прописная-строчная*** у "Р/римского", ***уместность употребления слова*** "Одигитрия" в соседстве с иконой Богоматери. Не надо учить меня жить, Ваши комменты отвлекают меня от работы. На этом общение закончено.

Answer (score 1):

Икона называется **"Богоматерь Римская" или "Спасение Римского народа"**, а   "Одигитрия" — тип иконографии.

Поэтому существуют варианты названия: кавычки, выбор прописной или строчной буквы, спасение/спасения.

Один из вариантов (падеж лучше бы исправить): **Икона Богоматери Одигитрия — “Спасение Римского народа”. VII в.**

http://www.icon-art.info/masterpiece.php?lng=ru&mst_id=2432

**Богоматерь Римская**
Salus populi romani — Спасение народа римского

Богородица Salus Populi Romani

Рим, VII век (?), поновления XII–XIII вв., базилика Санта Мария Маджоре.
Энкаустика, доска (?); 117 × 79 см.

Salus Populi Romani («**Спасение Римского народа**»), пожалуй, самый почитаемый из всех римских богородичных образов и один из немногих, культ которых не прерывался вплоть до наших дней. Дева Мария представлена **согласно иконографии «Одигитрии»**, с Младенцем на скрещенных руках, в левой руке — маппула, небольшой льняной плат, использовавшийся древнеримской знатью.